# Is there any way to run(preview) expo project on another network?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm making an app using expo, and want to preview my app in another network. Right now, I am able to run(preview) my App in the local network using expo-CLI command `expo start` but it works in the local network only. I also tried `expo start --tunnel` for another network, but it gives me an error

```
>Something went wrong
>Could not load exp://hr-s2k.nim***-bh***.Tapp.exp.direct:80
```

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnAch.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure in expo app you are signed in**